# Vertical scroll for a wrapping div

Tags: css, html, scroll

I'm trying to realize a kind of table with divs. The first "column" must be fixed and the others may scroll horizontally.
These things are achieved, now arrive the problem: the vertical scroll.

I'd like to have only one scroll bar that will scroll both div in the same way (synchronously), to reach this goal I've put the two divs inside another one but it doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="recipe_rows">
    <div class="recipe_first_col">
        <div class="recipe_row recipe_header">
            <!-- row for buttons -->
            <p>C1R1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="recipe_row">
            <!-- row for segment selection -->
            <p>C1R2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="recipe_row">
            <!-- row for setpoints -->
            <p>C1R3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="recipe_row">
            <!-- row for events -->
            <p>C1R4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="recipe_cols">
        <div class="recipe_row recipe_header">
            <!-- row for buttons -->
            <p>C2R1</p>
            <p>C3R1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="recipe_row">
            <!-- row for segment selection -->
            <p>C2R2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="recipe_row">
            <!-- row for setpoints -->
            <p>C2R3</p>
            <p>C3R3</p>
            <p>C4R3</p>
            <p>C5R3</p>
            <p>C6R3</p>
            <p>C7R3</p>
            <p>C8R3</p>
            <p>C9R3</p>
            <p>C10R3</p>
            <p>C11R3</p>
            <p>C12R3</p>
            <p>C13R3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="recipe_row">
            <p>C2R4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.recipe_rows {
    width: 99%;
    height: 180px;
    overflow: auto;
    line-height: 52px;
    clear: both;
    overflow-y:visible;
}

.recipe_rows p {
    float: left;
    width: 165px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.recipe_first_col {
    float: left;
    width: 175px;
    height: 99%;
    background: #eee;
    /*overflow: auto;*/
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.recipe_cols {
    height: 99%;
    margin-left: 175px;
    /*overflow: auto;*/
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.recipe_header {
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
    color: #fff;
    background: #006 url('../media/menu_blu.png');
}

.recipe_row {
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: inherit;
    clear: both;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaxMarkson/YjPcM/1/)

As you can see there's a 4th row which is cutted.
How can I obtain the vertical scroll for the external div?

Thanks to all

**EDIT**

Ok, I made something like what I need:
[JsFiddle v.2](http://jsfiddle.net/MaxMarkson/YjPcM/2/)

Now the problem is: it's possible to have the horizontal scrollbar not at the end of the "table" but fixed at the bottom of the div `recipe_cols`?

Comment: Its cut because your recipe rows class is too small for the height. You will have to increase the height here to have it not be cut.

Comment: Well, I know that the row is cutted because the height is too low...the example is used to show that no vertical scroll is shown

Comment: Add in the overflow-y:scroll; option to make a vertical scroll

Comment: If I add that option to the `recipe_rows` class the scrollbar is shown but it's impossible to scroll

Comment: you might like to look at using http://datatables.net/ it provides all the functionality you are attempting, plus much more.

Comment: Yes, I've already seen that plugin but it's really more than what I need. It's like something that my teacher said: "You're trying to kill a fly with a cannon"

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this is the behavior you wanted: [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7We6L/1/)

To do this, you need to wrap the rows in another div to enable vertical scrolling. For this one, just use absolute positioning to get it the right size.

Relevant code:

HTML

```
<div class="recipe_rows">
    <div class="recipe_first_col">
        <div class="recipe_row recipe_header">
            <!-- row for buttons -->
            <p>C1R1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="recipe_row">
            <!-- row for segment selection -->
            <p>C1R2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="recipe_row">
            <!-- row for setpoints -->
            <p>C1R3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="recipe_row">
            <!-- row for events -->
            <p>C1R4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="recipe_cols">
        <div class="recipe_row recipe_header">
            <!-- row for buttons -->
            <p>C2R1</p>
            <p>C3R1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row-scroll">
            <div class="recipe_row">
                <!-- row for segment selection -->
                <p>C2R2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="recipe_row">
                <!-- row for setpoints -->
                <p>C2R3</p>
                <p>C3R3</p>
                <p>C4R3</p>
                <p>C5R3</p>
                <p>C6R3</p>
                <p>C7R3</p>
                <p>C8R3</p>
                <p>C9R3</p>
                <p>C10R3</p>
                <p>C11R3</p>
                <p>C12R3</p>
                <p>C13R3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="recipe_row">
                <p>C2R4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.recipe-cols {
    position:relative;
}

.row-scroll {
    position:absolute;
    top:52px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: With your way only the white cells will scroll, I need that the first column scroll too

Comment: Ah, ok... you will need to change the HTML quite a bit to achieve what you want, then. Will see if I can do so quickly..

Comment: Ok, if you have idea try to explain...maybe I can do it on my own if someone put me on the correct rail-track ;)

Comment: Actually, sorry, but I don't think it is possible to include synched scrolling vertically between the first column and the others, but not synched scrolling horizontally... Not with Javascript or something, at least.

Comment: Ok, I'll accept javascript/jQuery but nothing too heavy because I've already have some heavy scripts in the page. PS: check the edit in the question ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?
[FIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/7We6L/2/)

***CSS***

```
.recipe_first_col {
    float: left;
    width: 175px;
    height: 99%;
    background: #eee;
    /*overflow: auto;*/
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: No, because in this case only the first column scroll, the others remain blocked.

Comment: Cell C2R4 is disappear and the cell C1R4 is out of the `first_col` div...it has white background